# Game of Life in pygame: How to be able to manually click on cells to activate/deactivate them?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, mouseevent, conways-game-of-life

Working on this Game of Life version in pygame. 
In the end I want to have two options to run the game: one where you can start the game and it runs automatically with a random grid and a game where the user starts with an empty grid and can activate/deactivate cells. 
Currently I only have the random grid mode and Im struggling with the activation/deactivation of cells. 
In handle_events() there is a function that allows the user to click on cells to activate them in the random grid if the game is paused, but for some reason it doesn't allow the user to deactivate those cells again. Also, it is overwritten in the next iteration.

Does anyone know how i can fix this? And what would be the best way to create two different game modes ("random game" and "user selects cell mode").

Thanks in advance

I have posted the code below.

```
import pygame
import random
import sys

grid_size = width, height = 400, 400
cell_size = 10
color_dead = 0, 0, 0  # Background
color_alive = 255, 255, 255  # alive cell, can be any color.  #orange = 255, 100, 0 #yellow = 255,255,0, # red=255,0,0 #Green 0,200,0
fps_max = 10


class GameOfLife:
    def __init__(self):
      #The screen
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Game of Life - Created by ") 
        self.FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(grid_size)
        self.clear_screen()  # you clear the screen before it starts running
        pygame.display.flip() #Update the full display Surface to the screen
        self.last_update_completed = 0
        #self.desired_milliseconds_between_updates = (1.0 / fps_max) * 1000
        self.active_grid = 0
        self.num_cols = int(width / cell_size)
        self.num_rows = int(height / cell_size)
        self.grids = []
        self.init_grids()
        self.set_grid()
        self.paused = False
        self.game_over = False

    def is_in_range(self, x, y):
        if x in range(self.x, self.x + self.size + 1) and y in range(self.y, self.y + self.size + 1):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def init_grids(self):

        def create_grid():
            rows = []
            for row_num in range(self.num_rows):
                list_of_columns = [0] * self.num_cols
                rows.append(list_of_columns)
            return rows

        self.grids.append(create_grid())
        self.grids.append(create_grid())
        self.active_grid = 0


        #print(self.grids[0])
        #print(rows)
        #print(type(rows))


    #set_grid(0)  = all dead
    #set_grid(1) = all alive
    #set_grid() = random
    #set_grid(None) = random
    def set_grid(self, value=None, grid =0):
       for r in range(self.num_rows):
           for c in range(self.num_cols):
                if value is None:
                    cell_value = random.choice([0,1])
                else:
                    cell_value = value
                self.grids[grid][r][c] = cell_value

    def draw_grid(self):
        self.clear_screen()  # you clear the screen before it starts running
        for c in range(self.num_cols):
            for r in range(self.num_rows):
                if self.grids[self.active_grid][r][c] == 1:
                    color = color_alive
                else:
                    color = color_dead

                #pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, color, ((c * cell_size + (cell_size / 2)),(r * cell_size + (cell_size / 2)), cell_size, cell_size) )
                posn = (int(c * cell_size + cell_size / 2),
                        int(r * cell_size + cell_size / 2))
                pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, color, posn, int(cell_size / 2), 0)
        pygame.display.flip()

    def clear_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(color_dead)

    def get_cell(self, r, c):
        try:
            cell_value = self.grids[self.active_grid][r][c]
        except:
            #print("Couldn't get cell value: row: %d, col %d" % (r, c))
            cell_value = 0
        return cell_value

    def check_cell_neighbors(self, row_index, col_index):
        # Get the number of alive cells surrounding the current cell
        # self.grids[self.active_grid][r][c]   #is the current cell
        num_alive_neighbors = 0
        num_alive_neighbors += self.get_cell(row_index - 1, col_index - 1)
        num_alive_neighbors += self.get_cell(row_index - 1, col_index)
        num_alive_neighbors += self.get_cell(row_index - 1, col_index + 1)
        num_alive_neighbors += self.get_cell(row_index, col_index - 1)
        num_alive_neighbors += self.get_cell(row_index, col_index + 1)
        num_alive_neighbors += self.get_cell(row_index + 1, col_index - 1)
        num_alive_neighbors += self.get_cell(row_index + 1, col_index)
        num_alive_neighbors += self.get_cell(row_index + 1, col_index + 1)

        #print(num_alive_neighbors)
        #print("alive neighbors: %d")

# Rules
#1 Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if by underpopulation.
#2 Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
#3 Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overpopulation.
#4 Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.


        if self.grids[self.active_grid][row_index][col_index] == 1: #Alive
            if num_alive_neighbors > 3:
                return 0  # it dies of overpopulation # More than three live neighbors, rule number 3.
            if num_alive_neighbors < 2:
                return 0  # it dies of underpopulation = Rule number 1 = fewer than two live neighbors
            if num_alive_neighbors == 2 or num_alive_neighbors == 3:  # If there are 3 or 4 neighbors, and the cell is alive, it stays alive.
                return 1  # Rule number 2. Two or three live neighbours, it continuous to live.
        elif self.grids[self.active_grid][row_index][col_index] == 0: #Dead
            if num_alive_neighbors ==3:
                return 1 #It comes to life.
        return self.grids[self.active_grid][row_index][col_index]

    def update_generation(self):
        """
        Inspect current generation state, prepare next generation
        :return:
        """
        self.set_grid(0, self.inactive_grid())
        for r in range(self.num_rows - 1):
            for c in range(self.num_cols - 1):
                next_gen_state = self.check_cell_neighbors(r, c)
                # Set inactive grid future cell state
                self.grids[self.inactive_grid()][r][c] = next_gen_state  # if it is zero, than is is 1. if it is 1, it is gonna be 0. Picks the offgrid.
        self.active_grid = self.inactive_grid()


        #inspect the current active generation
        # update the inactive grid to store next generation
        #swap out the active grid
        #self.set_grid(None) #This means that you randomize the grid

    def inactive_grid(self):
        return (self.active_grid + 1) % 2

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if self.paused:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if(event.button==1):
                        mousepos_x, mousepos_y = event.pos
                        r, c = ((mousepos_x - cell_size / 2) // cell_size,
                                (mousepos_y - cell_size / 2) // cell_size)
                        print(event.pos, '->', (r, c))  # Show result.
                        mousepos_x, mousepos_y = event.pos# Index Y rows down, X columns to the right
                        for col in range(self.num_cols):
                            for row in range(self.num_rows):
                                if self.grids[self.active_grid][col][row] == 1:
                                    color = color_dead
                                elif self.grids[self.active_grid][col][row] == 0:
                                    color = 255,0,255#color_alive


                        posn = (int(r * cell_size + cell_size / 2),
                                int(c * cell_size + cell_size / 2))
                        print(posn) 
                        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, color, posn, int(cell_size / 2), 0)
                pygame.display.flip()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.unicode == 's':
                    if self.paused:
                        self.paused = False
                        print("unpaused")
                    else:
                        self.paused = True
                        print("paused")
                #Randomizin the grid
                elif event.unicode == 'r':
                    print("randomizing the grid")
                    self.active_grid = 0
                    self.set_grid(None, self.active_grid) #randomizing
                    self.set_grid(0,self.inactive_grid()) #set to 0.
                    self.draw_grid() #Even if it is paused.
                # Quitfunction
                elif event.unicode == 'q':  #If I press q, game_over becomes TRUE, which returns/ends in the def run().
                    print("Quitting the grid")
                    self.game_over = True


                # print(event.unicode)
                # print("Key pressed")
                # print(event.unicode)

            # if event is keypress of "s" then pause the loop/game.
            #if event is keypress "r" then randomize grid
            # if event is keypress of "q"then quit
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.game_over:
                return #So if it is game_over by pressing Q, you leave the loop.
            self.handle_events()  # when you run, you want to handle the events
            if self.paused:
                continue
            self.update_generation()  # Upgrade the generation
            self.draw_grid()  # and draw the grid
            self.FPSCLOCK.tick(fps_max)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = GameOfLife()
    game.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're simply changing the color of the cells instead of *directly* changing the values themselves. So add the specific indexing and set the value to their opposite and that should fix both problems.

```
mousepos_x, mousepos_y = event.pos# Index Y rows down, X columns to the right
if self.grids[self.active_grid][int(mousepos_x / 10)][int(mousepos_y / 10)] == 1:
    color = color_dead
    self.grids[self.active_grid][int(mousepos_x / 10)][int(mousepos_y / 10)] = 0

elif self.grids[self.active_grid][int(mousepos_x / 10)][int(mousepos_y / 10)] == 0:
    color = 255,0,255#color_alive
    self.grids[self.active_grid][int(mousepos_x / 10)][int(mousepos_y / 10)] = 1
```

This should fix both problems.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried this, but it keeps giving my a syntax error:invalid syntax.  Any suggestion what may be wrong here?

Comment: Oh, this was an error on my end, made an edit to fix it. Sorry. @Fabio

Comment: Thanks it works now, i can now activate/deactivate cells. However, it still overwrites the cells in the next iteration. Any way to fix that?

Comment: I've changed my answer to remove the for loop which seemed to only wipe a bunch of cells of the board. But, as for the elements not appearing, I think whats happening is that they don't work on totally empty slots, but work on "Dead" cells, although I'm unsure of why as I cannot fully understand your code. I need some more context on how the grids interact and why there are apparently several of them. @Fabio

Comment: Pygasm: Once again it appears that you don't understand the code in the OP's question—although admittedly parts of it are somewhat incomprehensible. At any rate, using `[int(mousepos_x / 10)][int(mousepos_y / 10)]` to index the cell value in the grid is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do in the `handle_events()` function for handling mouse button clicks. Here's a version that will allow cells to be activated and deactived when clicked, and the changes are overwritten in the next generation (unless they all happened to die due to application of the generation update rules).

I don't think you need to have the different modes (e.g. "random" vs "user selects") because that can be accomplished via the various single-key commands you've already implemented, although you woujld need to add one more that allowed manual clearing of the grid.

```
def handle_events(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if self.paused:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if(event.button==1):
                    mousepos_x, mousepos_y = event.pos
                    c, r = (int((mousepos_x - cell_size / 2) // cell_size),
                            int((mousepos_y - cell_size / 2) // cell_size))
                    #print(event.pos, '->', (r, c))  # Show result.
                    if r in range(self.num_rows) and c in range(self.num_cols):
                        # Toggle state of cell: active <--> inactive
                        if self.grids[self.active_grid][r][c] == 1:
                            self.grids[self.active_grid][r][c] = 0
                            color = color_dead
                        else:
                            self.grids[self.active_grid][r][c] = 1
                            color = color_alive
                        # Redraw cell in its new color.
                        posn = (int(c * cell_size + cell_size / 2),
                                int(r * cell_size + cell_size / 2))
                        #print('  posn:', posn)
                        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, color, posn, int(cell_size / 2), 0)

                        pygame.display.flip()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.unicode == 's':
                .
                .
                .
```